# Looping in pandas and apply regular expressions

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have the following script to selct the columns in my data set :

```
 df_c = pd.DataFrame(df, columns =['Year','Month','Title','Term','date','Company','Location'])
```

Im applying the following code as a find and replace to each variable separately:

```
 df_c['Location'] = df_c['Location'].str.replace(',', '')
```

Lets say I have 20 variables how would I do to apply the code to all variables at same time? looping "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with `regex=True` for replace substrings:

```
df_c = df_c.replace(',', '', regex=True)
```

If want apply replace only to some columns:

```
cols = ['Year','Month','Title','Term']

df_c[cols] = df_c[cols].replace(',', '', regex=True)
```